# ubuntu libimobiledevice ios 14 focal 20.04

Tags: 20.04, backup, iphone, ios

**current behavior**

When trying to backup my ios 14 on my ubuntu 20.04 I have the below error

```
idevicebackup2 backup /home/jb/iphone_backup_tmp/
Backup directory is "/home/jb/iphone_backup_tmp/"
Started "com.apple.mobilebackup2" service on port 52815.
Could not perform backup protocol version exchange, error code -1
```

I have an another ios 13 device and backup is working fine.

When trying to install the latest version from their official website https://libimobiledevice.org/#get-started
I got the below error

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice usbmuxd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libimobiledevice
```

**expected behavior**

be able to install the latest version of libimobiledevice and backup my ios 14 device via libimobiledevice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up on this [issue discussion](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/1067) and adapt one of the [script](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/1067#issuecomment-726234592) provided in it

```
sudo apt install build-essential checkinstall git autoconf automake libtool-bin libssl-dev pkg-config cython libusb-1.0-0-dev
git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist
git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libusbmuxd
git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice
git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice-glue
git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/usbmuxd
cd libplist
./autogen.sh
make && sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
cd ..
cd libimobiledevice-glue
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig ./autogen.sh --enable-debug
make && sudo make install
cd ..
cd libusbmuxd
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig ./autogen.sh
make && sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
cd ..
cd libimobiledevice
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig ./autogen.sh --enable-debug
make && sudo make install
cd ..
cd usbmuxd
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --runstatedir=/run
make && sudo make install
sudo killall usbmuxd

rm -fr libplist/ libusbmuxd/ libimobiledevice/ usbmuxd/ libimobiledevice-glue/
```

Comment: I wasted the half of the day to setup latest libimobiledevice and still didn't manage to connect my iPhone to Chrome. What worked for me was https://inspect.dev/. They want money, but you can tempmail the trial.